# Laravel 5 : [Call to a member function getAction() on a non-object

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-routing

In my Controller, I have

```
Route::getCurrentRoute()->getAction()['as']
```

Everything works well in the browser but as soon as I type

```
php artisan route:list
```

in the terminal I have this exception

```
[Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException]
Call to a member function getAction() on a non-object
```

If I comment this line everything works well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems obvious doesn't it?

Get current route in a browser will return the currently visited route. In the terminal you do not have such a request. Laravel will return null when asking what route is visited. You would have to check for the return value before calling getAction.

Comment: May be obvious for you :)) I foolishly thought when we type a  `php artisan route;list`it will just evaluate routes.php.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this code...

```
if(!App::runningInConsole()){
    Route::getCurrentRoute()->getAction()['as'];
}
```

when you run artisan command it will not get an error.