# Artisan error logging verbose level

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-artisan, verbose

I have the following error when I try to run the artisan command `php artisan route:list`:

```
[Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException]  
Call to a member function getAction() on a non-object
```

Because I have no idea where this happens, I'm trying to change the artisan verbose level to debug. `artisan help` tells me this:

```
--verbose (-v|vv|vvv) Increase the verbosity of messages: 1 for normal output, 2 for more verbose output and 3 for debug
```

But I have no idea how to use this. I've tried every combination but nothing seems to work. Can anybody tell me how to use the `php artisan route:list` command in debug mode?

Answer (score 11):

`php artisan route:list -vvv` should work. The syntax is as follows: `php artisan route:list [options]`

Answer (score 0):

> Get current route in a browser will return the currently visited
>   route.  In the terminal you do not such a request.  Laravel will
>   return null when asking what route is visited. You would have to check
>   for the return value before calling getAction.

Source [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30826725/laravel-5-call-to-a-member-function-getaction-on-a-non-object).

Comment: You're probably right that that is the mistake I'm making somewhere in my code, but I want Artisan to tell me WHERE in my code, not only that that is the exception...