# Get Laravel 5 controller name in boot method

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, php-7

I have some theme in laravel that boot via this in my Custom package

```
 $this->app->makeWith( $themeClass, [ $this->app ] )
```

How I can get current controller name? I need this for know if this page is post or product and get id this product

in view works fine this code

```
            $routeArray = app( 'request' )->route()->getAction();
            $controllerAction = class_basename( $routeArray['controller'] );
```

but in theme not works

```
Call to a member function getAction() on null
```

I use laravel 5.6

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel 5 : \[Call to a member function getAction() on a non-object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30826725/laravel-5-call-to-a-member-function-getaction-on-a-non-object)

Comment: apparently you do not read anything at all, the place to advise a workaround

Answer (score 0):

you can get `controller name` using below code

```
$routeArray = app('request')->route()->getAction();
$controllerAction = class_basename($routeArray['controller']);
list($controller, $action) = explode('@', $controllerAction);

$controller = $routeArray['as'];
echo $controller;exit;
```

in `$routeArray` have all `controller,method, as name` etc so you can easily get value you want.